# Adapting background to screen with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am new to iOS and SpriteKit development, and I want to make a small game with a scrolling background in landscape mode only. So far I have gotten my background to scroll, but my problem is that I don't know to make the background image fit the view/scene correctly.

I have a 2040x768 background image, but I can change it to any size; I just had no idea which size to go with to make it fit. It's in `Images.xcassets` as 1x. I have added it to my view as follows.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Background")
        let background = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)
        background.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(background)
    }
}
```

The result is that the background image fills the screen, but that the bottom and top of the image is cut off - or rather "outside" of the screen. The background image has grass at the bottom, but this is not visible. The scene's `scaleMode` is set to `AspectFill`. If I set it to `AspectFit`, the full height of the image is visible, but then the width of the scene is reduced (in case I am using the wrong terminology here, a black space is visible both to the left and right of the background image).

Also, in my code, I have added a 1px high rectangle without any sprite to be the ground. I added an object with physics which is supposed to drop to the ground. The problem is that the ground rectangle is added "below" the screen. The object stops fine when it hits the ground; this is just not visible. I have tested this with with multiple falling objects, and they stack on top of each other, and after adding a couple, they become visible, which means that the ground is indeed there; it's just not on the screen. So the ground is at the bottom of the background image, which is off the screen. I thought this information might help explain the situation. Here is how I add the ground node.

```
var ground = SKNode()
ground.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 1))
ground.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
self.addChild(ground)
```

How do I make the full background image visible and have it adapt to the screen size of the device? I tried to add `background.size = self.frame.size`, which makes everything smaller, but the result is essentially the same. Do I have to make multiple copies of the background in different sizes? If so, which sizes, and how do I choose which one is displayed? I would prefer a dynamic solution, but I just want this to work.

So basically I just need my entire background image to fit the screen. As long as it fits vertically, then it is okay if it is not wide enough (as long as the size of the scene remains the same) by keeping the aspect ratio, because it is a scrolling background, so I can add another one next to it horizontally.

There might be resources out there explaining this, but I have really searched for days and have not found the solution. Please provide as much information and details as you can. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple, give your node size of your Scene.

```
background.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)
```

you can change your node size in CGSizeMake.

```
ground = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height / 10)
```

EDIT:

Set background node to be in middle

```
background.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2)
```

Comment: Isn't the first the same as `background.size = self.frame.size` as in the question? The position of my background should already be at the center with the code in the question. Anyways, I tried your variations, and the result is unfortunately the same.

Comment: You need to change this:      

     **if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {**

 To something like this

IN Objective-c it looks like this: (i dont know now in swift)
**MainMenuScene *scene = [MainMenuScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];**

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked! I did it like this in Swift: `scene.size = skView.bounds.size` after having instantiated the scene.